# CSR matrix-matrix products algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I found a lot of examples and algorithms on CSR matrix creation, visualize, product with vector. But I didn't found any algorithm on CSR-matrix * CSR-matrix product.

I found a nice [link](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/561/Syllabus/3-C/sparse.html) in which is explained the matrix dot vector product.

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the references and source code of some libraries implemented this operation

- [SuiteSparse](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) has SSMULT
- [PETSc](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/) is a library collection and has [MatMatMult](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatMatMult.html)
- [SPARSEKIT](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/sparsekit/sparsekit.html) has AMUB

Or even easier you could just use one of these libraries.